# React.js redirect after no result found from backend fetch using useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

*How to redirect to a 404 component if i do not receive any data from axios fetch after using the useFetch*

```
function EditUser() {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const [userFound, setUserFound] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      axios.get(`/api/user/${id}`).then((response) => {
        if (response.data.length > 0) {
          console.log(response);
          setUserFound(true);
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, []);

  if (!userFound) {
    <Redirect to="/home" />; // not working even that the state is false
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{id}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: are you using `react-router`?

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald Yes I am .

Comment: not sure if this will fix it, but what if you change the initial state to `undefined` and then in the `if` part add an `else` statement saying `setUserFound(false)`

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
            window.location.assign("/home");
```

the path is relative meaning that if you are in [www.mypage.com/edit](http://www.mypage.com/edit) and want to go to [www.mypage.com/home](http://www.mypage.com/home) you would have to write

```
window.location.assign("../home");
```

Comment: Is it secure to use this approach?

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure cause I haven't dealt with security issues alternatively I would create a state variable called redirect and I would use different routng depending on its value gonna post some example code in the ansers

Answer (score 0):

Alternatenely I would just avoid mixing html in js meaning I would approach it like this

```
  return (
<>
userfound ?
    <div>
      <h1>{id}</h1>
    </div>
: <Redirect to="/home" />
</>
  );
```

something among these lines should work
Or a while back I used this approach:

```
          <Route path="/users" component={userfound ? CurrentPage: RedirectPage} />
```

where CurrentPage would contain ... and redirect your html redirect request. I' ve only used it in Route but I guess it exists in other elements as well